# SP Services Published Pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page, spservices

Does any know how to pull published pages using SPServices ?

I am able pull using Object model, but site seems slower

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        PublishingPageCollection oPubPages = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(oWeb).GetPublishingPages();
        foreach (PublishingPage oPage in oPubPages)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Object Model code? Also I don't think you can get an performance gain with WebService calls.

Comment: What do you want to do with them? It's just a GetListItems operation, pass in your desired CAML to retrieve what you want, http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists.

Comment: I am looking to pull only published pages through Sp Services

Answer (score 0):

The basic equivalent would be:

```
 $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Pages",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        //do something with each page
      });
    }
  });
```

You'd most likely want to include a CAMLQuery to get the specific pages you want.